# Action redirecionar outra Action utilizando PartialViewResult

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ajax

```
public PartialViewResult Index(string quantidadeRegistro)
    {
        int qtd;
        int.TryParse(quantidadeRegistro, out qtd);
        var bdPedido = PedidosAplicacaoConstrutor.PedidosAplicacaoEF();
        var bdCliente = ClientesAplicacaoConstrutor.ClientesAplicacaoEF();
        IEnumerable<Pedidos> pedidos;
        if (qtd < 1)
            pedidos = bdPedido.ListarTodos().OrderByDescending(x => x.ID);
        else
            pedidos = bdPedido.ListarTodos().OrderByDescending(x => x.ID).Take(qtd);
        ViewData["Clientes"] = bdCliente.ListarTodos();
        return PartialView(pedidos);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public PartialViewResult Editar(FormCollection collection)
    {
        var bdPedido = PedidosAplicacaoConstrutor.PedidosAplicacaoEF();
        var status = collection["status"];
        var id = collection["ID"];

        var pedido = bdPedido.ListarPorId(id);
        pedido.Status = status;
        bdPedido.Salvar(pedido);


        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }


      function Open(url) {
        $('#Conteudo').empty().append('<div id="loader"><img src="/Content/Images/loading.gif"/></div>');
        $.get(url,function(response){
            $('#Conteudo').html(response);
            $('#loader').remove();
        });
    }

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Salvar</button>
```

Não consigo fazer com que o Editar mande para o Index.
Substitui o PartialViewResult do Editar por ActionResult dá certo, porém daí perco o "layout" da página, pois utilizo AJAX.

Comment: Para não perder o layout, Diego, você deve usar o handler [`.on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/). Se você postar o seu AJAX, posso te ajudar melhor.

Comment: Editei o post, veja se é isso!

Comment: Quem é que chama essa sua função `Open`?

Comment: Os HyperLinks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O redirect do asp, não vai ter efeito para uma chamada em ajax, o que você pode fazer é fazer o redirect depois da chamada ajax, com javascript.

Algo assim:

```js
function Open(url, redirect) {
    $('#Conteudo').empty().append('<div id="loader"><img src="/Content/Images/loading.gif"/></div>');
    $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        url : url,
        // aqui você serializa seu form
        data: $("form").find(":input").serialize(),
        success : function(response) {
            if (redirect) {
                $("#Conteudo").load(redirect, function() {
                    $('#loader').remove();
                });
            } else {
                $('#Conteudo').html(response);
                $('#loader').remove();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Sua chamada ficaria assim, por exemplo:

```js
$("form").submit(function(event) {
    Open("/meucontroller/editar", "/meucontroller/index");
});
```

O metódo [load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) do JQuery vai carregar a pagina sem perder o layout, como acredito que você queira.

Não sei se isso é viável para você.

Comment: Não intendi @Fernando, isso ficaria no botão salvar?

Comment: @DiegoZanardo, essa não é uma chamada ajax?

Comment: Tenho uma PartialView com um formulário que tem um submit. Esse submit manda pra "public PartialViewResult Editar(FormCollection collection){}", este faz uma edição no banco, então preciso que retorne para o Index sem perder o layout.

Comment: @DiegoZanardo, editei minha resposta, veja se agora atente a suas necessidades.

Comment: eu preciso que seja passado por post!

Comment: @DiegoZanardo, mas dai o problema nem é mais o redirect, dai você tem que trocar o $.get por [$.post](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)

Comment: @DiegoZanardo, editei novamente de uma olhada.

Comment: ainda está meio confuso para mim. Eu coloquei o meu botão salvar no post. Mas pelo que eu entendi, eu vou ter que alterar o botão salvar para um onclick que aponta para o open. Isso? E passar os parametros através do DATA!

Comment: e como eu trataria isso na Action?

Comment: @DiegoZanardo, não é necessário, você pode fazer como postei na resposta acima, mas também pode fazer no botão.

Comment: O return da minha action ficaria como?

Comment: @DiegoZanardo, de uma olhada [aqui](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8561038/return-new-emptyresult-vs-return-null).

Comment: Consegui aqui... Obrigado pela ajuda.